# How to get dictionary response instead of list in json-server pagination?

Tags: pagination, json-server

I am trying to paginate records in `typicode json-server`. I have db.json and routes.json files. In db.json file I have data in the following manner,

```
{    
    "data": [
        {
            "event_name": "molestias, architecto dolor",
            "id": "repellendus esse modi veniam veniam adipisicing",
        }
    ],
    "page": 0
},
{
    "data": [
        {
            "event_name": "molestiassds, fg565 dolor",
            "id": "repellendus esse modi sdsd veniam veniam adipisicing",
        },
    ],
    "page": 1
}
```

When I hit URL http://localhost:3000/global_exclusions?page=1, it returns me list of data.

```
[ { "data": [ { "event_name": "molestiassds, fg565 dolor", "id": "repellendus esse modi sdsd veniam veniam adipisicing", }, ], "page": 1 } ]
```

But, I want just
{ "data": [ { "event_name": "molestiassds, fg565 dolor", "id": "repellendus esse modi sdsd veniam veniam adipisicing", }, ], "page": 1 }

Is there any specific change I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar requirement and the easiest way around I could find was creating a NodeJs module.
Using NodeJs gives one full control over the request and response format/transformations.

1. Create a file named `index.js` or something favorable
2. Import the `json-server` package and add the following logic.
3. Start the server using `node index.js`

```js
const jsonServer = require('json-server');

const server = jsonServer.create(); 
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json'); //the database 
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();

//overwrite the router render method.
// this should be done before passing the router to server
router.render = (req, res) => {
    res.jsonp({
      data: res.locals.data
    });

}

server.use(middlewares);
server.use(router);

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('JSON Server is running');
})
```

Reference https://github.com/typicode/json-server/blob/1759c986b57302be89742375525d238b3af66039/README.md#module